# Is it safe pushing nested folders to GitHub?

Tags: git, github, directory, repository

For example, instead of pushing JS project repos one by one to GH, what if make them subfolders to a "JS projects" main folder and then push it?
Just want to make sure if that's safe from conflicts on the long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conflicts will appear if you have different contributors making changes in the same piece of code. That has nothing to do in the decision of putting them under the same project or not.

How you organize your repos is your decision in terms of how do you want to track the changes in every subproject. If you think that it's a good idea to have them grouped, then maybe it is. Every design is based on decisions and you have to make one for your design.

Hope that my ambiguous answer had helped you to make a non ambiguous decision!

Comment: I see. I've noticed that apparently most people just push their projects in separate folders. But I believe that grouping them makes it more organized to show them as portfolio...

Comment: As I told you before, think in your design. if your main goal is to make your own portfolio, then everything in the same repository should be fine. How do you want to segmentate your projects/subprojects is your real question. Think in your present and future needs, and you have your answer! My recommendation is that you could group small projects in the same repository, but big projects should be placed in individual repositories :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Git (and GitHub) handles directories and nested directories just fine. As long as you, as a user, can still find your way around the directory structure, there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!